# "One of the" or "an"?

Tags: articles

1. I turned on the screen and it presented me a bunch of options. I clicked on ***one of the options*** to turn off the entire system.

In the above sentence does "one of the options" imply that there were multiple options to turn off the system or was there just one and I clicked ***that one*** of the options?

2. I turned on the screen and it presented me a bunch of options. I clicked on ***an option*** to turn off the entire system.

Here I used "an option", can I use this if I know that the listener doesn't know that there was an option to turn off the system? So I used "an option". Is this correct even if there was only one option to turn off the system?

Comment: To me, both of them sound like there was more than one option that would turn off the system.  If there was only one option that would turn off the system, I would say "**the** option to turn off the system."

Comment: But what if the listener doesn't know there is an option to turn of the system, then I would have to use "an option" because it's indefinite.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the listener knows that.  There is still only one.  I think you may not have grasped exactly what "indefinite" means - it means something like "one of any" or "an unspecified one", not "unknown".  I'm not saying that **an** is completely wrong, it just seems slightly less common or fluent here.

Comment: So I can use "a" or "one of the" if there are multiple items without having any subtle difference? For e.g.  "He slammed the door with such impact that a glass on a nearby table fell down" So this means there were multiple glasses on the table?

Comment: In your example about the glass, I don't think that "a glass on a nearby table" means there was more than one.  "A glass" means "an arbitrary glass", possibly but not necessarily one of many.  For example, I might look out the window and say, "I see a man with a green hat" - that doesn't mean I see more than one man but only one has a green hat, it simply means that I see one, of many men existing in the world; maybe I see other men with other hats and maybe I don't.

Comment: But how do I say it if I wanted to say a glass of many glasses on a nearby table fell down? Is this correct- He slammed the door with such impact that a glass of three glasses on a nearby table fell down" .

Comment: If I had to specify that it was one of many, I think the most natural way would be "one of the three glasses".

Comment: But this uses "one of the", I never introduced the three glasses so why am I using "the"? Wouldn't the listener ask "What 3 glasses?"

Comment: The three that are on the table.  But I think this question is veering into philosophy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132961/discussion-between-english-more-exc-than-laws-and-stangdon).

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **I clicked on one of the options to turn off the entire system.**

This *does* suggest there were several options to switch the system off.

There are several ways to rewrite it.

**I clicked on the option to turn off the entire system.**

**I clicked on one of the options: to switch off the entire system.**

Or, if the system *was* successfully turned off, you could say,

**I clicked on one of the options **and turned** off the entire system.**

Your second idea repeats "option" and sounds awkward.

Comment: stangdon already came up with my first suggestion. It's the best one.

Comment: So I can use "a" or "one of the" if there are multiple items without having any subtle difference? For e.g. "He slammed the door with such impact that a glass on a nearby table fell down" So this means there were multiple glasses on the table?

Comment: "**A** glass on a nearby table" does not tell us if it is the only glass. There may or may not be others.  "**The** glass on a nearby table" tells us there is only one glass. "**A** glass on **the** nearby table" tells us there is only one table nearby.

Comment: So, in my 2nd sentence why is "an option" sounding awkward? It is not simply "an option" , it is "an option to turn off the entire system". Also please consider this example, "The man from your company called", so this means only one man called so it's "the man" which doesn't make sense.